How to use multiple GTests in CMake
I have the following project structure:
- include
  - func.h
- src
  - main.cpp
  - func.cpp
- tests
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - func1_test.cpp
  - func2_test.cpp
- CMakeLists.txt

Here is the root CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12)

option(BUILD_TESTS "BuildTests" ON)
set(PROJECT_VERSION "0.0.3" CACHE INTERNAL "Version")

project ("test_project" VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
add_executable (test_project "src/main.cpp" "src/func.cpp" "include/func.h")
include_directories("include")

set_property(TARGET test_project PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)

# Enable Hot Reload for MSVC compilers if supported.
if (POLICY CMP0141)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0141 NEW)
  set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "$<IF:$<AND:$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:EditAndContinue>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>>")
endif()

set_target_properties(test_project
    PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
)

# Tests.
if(BUILD_TESTS)
    enable_testing()
    add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()

And here is tests CMakeLists.txt:
include(FetchContent)
if (POLICY CMP0135)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0135 NEW)
endif()
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/refs/tags/v1.14.0.zip
)
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

include(GoogleTest)

set(TestsToRun
  func1_test.cpp
  func2_test.cpp
)
create_test_sourcelist (Tests CppTests.cpp ${TestsToRun})
add_executable (CppTests ${Tests})
target_include_directories(CppTests PRIVATE "include")
set_property(TARGET CppTests PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
target_link_libraries(CppTests GTest::gtest_main)
set_target_properties(CppTests
    PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
)
foreach (test ${TestsToRun})
    get_filename_component (TName ${test} NAME_WE)
    add_test (NAME ${TName} COMMAND CppTests ${TName})
    #gtest_discover_tests(${test})
endforeach ()

func.h:
#pragma once
int func1();
int func2();

func.cpp:
#include "func.h"

int func1()
{
    return 33;
}

int func2()
{
    return 77;
}

I'm trying to use create_test_sourcelist from CMake docs. But building gives me the following error:
[main] Building folder: /home/user/Code/Test/build/linux-debug 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/user/Code/Test/build/linux-debug --parallel 22 --
[build] [ 20%] Built target test_project
[build] [ 33%] Built target gtest
[build] [ 46%] Built target gtest_main
[build] [ 60%] Built target gmock
[build] [ 73%] Built target gmock_main
[build] [ 80%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/CppTests
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/CppTests.dir/CppTests.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x8): undefined reference to `func1_test(int, char**)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/CppTests.dir/CppTests.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x18): undefined reference to `func2_test(int, char**)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/CppTests.dir/func1_test.cpp.o: in function `Func1Test_Func1Test_Test::TestBody()':
[build] /home/user/Code/Test/tests/func1_test.cpp:9:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `func1()'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/CppTests.dir/func2_test.cpp.o: in function `Func21Test_Func2Test_Test::TestBody()':
[build] /home/user/Code/Test/tests/func2_test.cpp:9:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `func2()'
[build] collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] gmake[2]: *** [tests/CMakeFiles/CppTests.dir/build.make:131: bin/CppTests] Error 1
[build] gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:180: tests/CMakeFiles/CppTests.dir/all] Error 2
[build] gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
[proc] The command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/user/Code/Test/build/linux-debug --parallel 22 -- exited with code: 2
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:00.352
[build] Build finished with exit code 2

Note, I'm commented the gtest_discover_tests call because I dont understand should I use it and what var should I use for it.
Here is func1_test.cpp (func2_test.cpp looks similar):
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include "../include/func.h"

TEST(Func1Test, Func1Test)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(func1(), 33);
}


"I'm trying to use create_test_sourcelist" - you don't need it. Just use add_executable("CppTests" "CppTests.cpp" "func1_test.cpp" " func2_test.cpp" "func.cpp")

First, to test the code in func.cpp, you should create a library, and then link it to both your main executable, and your tests. Then, I see that you created one test executable CppTests, if you want it to be executable with CTest, i.e. by typing make test, it's just enough to: add_test(MyTest ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/CppTests)

Main problem is that sources which should be tested are build as part of target executable: test_project!  You need a library which you will link to your executable and to your tests.
Rearrange sources this way:
- funlib
  - include
      - funlib
          - func.h
  - src
      - func.cpp
  - CMakeLists.txt
- demo_app
  - main.cpp
  - CMakeLists.txt
- tests
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - func1_test.cpp
  - func2_test.cpp
- CMakeLists.txt

Where:

funlib - is directory for library

include is for public headers of library (public interface of the library)
src - is for funlibs sources and private headers


demo_app your final product which should do as little and possible and just call some library functions.
tests - actual tests for test lib

CMakelists.txt
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12)

option(BUILD_TESTS "BuildTests" ON)
set(PROJECT_VERSION "0.0.3" CACHE INTERNAL "Version")
project (test_project VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})

add_subdirectory(funlib)
add_subdirectory(demo_app)
if(BUILD_TESTS)
    add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()

funlib/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(funlib # STATIC?
   src/func.cpp
   include/funlib/func.h
)

target_include_directories(funlib
   PUBLIC include
   PRIVATE src include/funlib)

Note that in this form you will do #include <funlib/func.h> in other targets to import a function.
demo_app/CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(demo_app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(demo_app PUBLIC funlib)

tests/CMakeLists.txt
# importing gtest ....
# I do not like how you do it, but this is off topic of your question

add_executable(CppTests 
    func1_test.cpp
    func2_test.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(CppTests PUBLIC GTest::gtest_main funlib)

gtest_discover_tests(CppTests)

Note include path is already address in in funlib you should not do it in CppTests.

If funlib is a shared library and you've hidden the symbols (which is default in Windows dlls), do you add the binary directory of funlib to path?

if you have dynamic library which delivers some functionality, you have to expose public API to the world that includes test. You should test only public API (not implementation details of the library).
To expose pubic API on Windows cmake delivers auto generated macros and header files see GenerateExportHeader

The reason I'm asking is because I did what OP did, of setting all binaries to the same directory. Come to think of it, I'll just put add_subdirectory(demo_app) within a if(PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL).
